# Combine Java with Kotlin in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

> I am slightly moving from Java to Kotlin in android app development,
>   but there are some cases where I don't want to code in Kotlin and want
>   those particular cases be written in Java:

- It is effort-saving that Kotlin removes extra usage of
  `findViewByIds`
- I know that it is now `null-safety` which oppositely Java always triggered with `NullPointerException`
- `Lambda` expressions are also provided and many other features.

But still, some of my codes cannot be written in Kotlin such as `static` members or `non-primitive` fields.

Kotlin annotations actually can replace those `static members`. But love some coding features of Java and dont want to leave that.

> **My question is can I combine Java and Kotlin together?**

Comment: Yes. Did you try? `src/main/java` and `src/main/kotlin` . https://developer.android.com/kotlin/get-started.html#add-kotlin

Comment: Didnt get exactly what you  meant @cricket_007?

Comment: Read the link ;)

Comment: What do you mean by non-primitive fields? https://ideone.com/QNURYB

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If your question is can you use kotlin files in java files and vice versa then the answer is yes.

If you are asking if you can use kotlin syntax in java files and vice versa then the answer is no.

To use kotlin code in a java class you are simply using the class like any other java class

Answer (score 5):

You can have in your project Java and Kotlin Class and Activities.

The same Class can't have Java and Kotlin. 
You can convert a Java file to Kotlin with **Ctrl+Alt+Shift+K** or just double tap SHIFT and search for **Convert Java to Kotlin**

Answer (score 3):

You can create a java similar **static** variables using **companion object**.

You can easily create **singleton** in Kotlin using **object**.

After I leant kotlin. I have migrated all my codes to Kotlin.

Comment: Yes I can create, But how about merging two Languages together to work on

Comment: Why not its interoperable. So you can call java codes from kotlin and vise versa

Comment: Do you have to write all code again for Kotlin, can Android Studio translate your existing Java code to Kotlin? I would like to migrate to Kotlin, since i'm learning Swift now. I have 4 years of Java experience but i don't want to write all code for all my apps again.

Comment: Don't write again. Android studio convert java code to kotlin. Control + Alt + shift + k, by this shortcut you can migrate your java code as kotlin. However, minor changes should be done by you to complete the operation.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it's interop you can't mix Java and Kotlin in the same file.

If you really want to have static methods/variables you can use an `companion object`. You can also access create a "real" static method in your JVM by using `@JvmStatic`.

Simple sample is:

```
companion object {  
    @JvmStatic 
    fun newInstance() ) SampleFragment()
}
```

which equals to

```
public static SampleFragment() { return new SampleFragment(); }
```

By using `@JvmStatic` you can use Java to access your Static methods like before.